# can not resolve method setText(java.lang.String[])- Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I don't know why I am getting this error in Android Studio, this is quite a simple command that I am executing. The code is provided below. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am getting the error in the last line of code.

```
 String[] sadThought = {"a", "sad", "Thought"};
 String[] sadRandom ={(sadThought[new Random().nextInt(sadThought.length)])};

    TvSad.setText(sadRandom);
```

Comment: It is a textview, I don't know what else to provide.

Comment: I would say from the time these variables came into existence till the code you have shown.  (at least written if you can't post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this

```
TvSad.setText(sadThought[new Random().nextInt(sadThought.length)]);
```

Comment: It makes it easier, it works, but if anyone knows why the error is coming, I want to know

Comment: @user5145575 Again, **What is `TvSad`**??

Comment: @tnw the error was sadRandom is define as a array and he is passing an String array to textView , and textView is expecting String

Comment: @user5145575 you were defining sadRandom as an String array but actually you should have define as a String because textView takes a String in textView.SetText() as a Parameter

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'm sorry I am new

Comment: @user5145575 if my answer helped you kindly mark as tick

Comment: I will, it is asking me to wait

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create a separate array to get a random string from your sadThought array. You can try:

```
TvSad.setText(sadThought[new Random().nextInt(sadThought.length)]);
```

Also, make sure your `TvSad` is an instance of textView or EditText or other widgets that support `.setText(..)` method.